# Splitting an application across AWS and Heroku

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, heroku

My application is currently 100% managed by Heroku. A few endpoints on the application depend on very slow external resources.  Heroku occasionally kills these requests if they hit 30 seconds.<sup>[[1]](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)</sup> Unfortunately, the speed of these requests is out of my control, Heroku does not make exceptions on this timeout, and [H12 timeouts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout) are not acceptable.

I like what Heroku offers so I would like to keep as much of the application as possible on Heroku and then move the required pieces to AWS.

The application is Ruby on Rails using Postgres. I know what routes I want to run on AWS, what other parts of the application have to move in order to keep the remainder on Heroku?

Comment: Have you thought about requesting these external resources in a background job, and then reading the response from a cache?